# Why does the program throw an OutOfMemoryError on a specific smartphone?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

Wrote a graphical game program. While I was writing tests on emulators and on a smartphone. Everything worked well. Then he decided to try it on another smartphone - the program falls out after a short period of time. Throws an error - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 576012 byte allocation with 45728 free bytes and 44KB until OOM`

Looked at the size of used memory using Profiler in AndroidStudio.

I got this result for a smartphone on which the program is running normally (Available RAM - 750MB, version android 7.1.1):

```
Total - 115MB; Java - 74MB; Native - 5,8MB; Graphics - 7,6MB; Stack - 0,6MB; Code - 21,5 MB; Others - 5MB.
```

All values are constant except Java. This parameter grows to about - 90MB. Then the garbage collector removes all unnecessary and the parameter (Java) is again lowered to the initial value.

On another smartphone, everything works well too (Available RAM - 500MB, android version - 10):

```
Total - 161MB; Java - 13MB; Native - 100MB; Graphics - 9MB; Stack - 0,6MB; Code - 34 MB; Others - 7MB.
```

In this case, only the Native parameter changes from 60 to 100MB

On the 3rd smartphone, the program crashes after 1-2 minutes of the game. Data from Profiler:

```
Total - 166MB; Java - 81MB; Native - 11MB; Graphics - 35MB; Stack - 0,6MB; Code - 29 MB; Others - 5MB.
```

In this case, only the Java parameter changes from 70 to 80MB (approximately) Throws an error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 576012 byte allocation with 45728 free bytes and 44KB until OOM
(Available RAM - 400MB, android version - 7.0)
I noticed that the 3rd smartphone loads the Graphics parameter more strongly, has less free RAM, and the android version is 7.0. I don’t understand whether this can affect the appearance of the error.

Tell me what could be the problem?

I post a fragment of the LOG file:

```
2021-02-26 12:51:22,824 [6294715]   INFO - ools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask - Installing application: com.medinq.superlines 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,291 [6295182]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284363961ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : installer 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,291 [6295182]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284363965ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : Command Dump 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,291 [6295182]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284363966ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : get process ids 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364116ms LOG_ERR [22751][22751] : Could not get package user id: run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted
 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364117ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364117ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : CmdCommand::GetApksFromDump 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : processing APK 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:25,216 [6297107]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - Install successfully finished in 2 s 382 ms.. App restart successful without requiring a re-install. 
2021-02-26 12:51:26,834 [6298725]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - startCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:52:04,874 [6336765]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:52:04,874 [6336765]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopAll() 
2021-02-26 12:52:19,115 [6351006]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2021-02-26 12:52:19,645 [6351536]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appRegistry took 16 ms 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,487 [6456378]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,503 [6456394]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,519 [6456410]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [-Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=10.4.1.1, -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Ura\AppData\Local\Temp\1614333244503-0, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=24, -Pandroid.injected.build.density=xxhdpi, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi] 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,519 [6456410]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=10.4.1.1 -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Ura\AppData\Local\Temp\1614333244503-0 -Pandroid.injected.build.api=24 -Pandroid.injected.build.density=xxhdpi -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,266 [6457157]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 750 ms 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,267 [6457158]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models. 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,267 [6457158]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, success = true 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,275 [6457166]   INFO - idea.run.AndroidProcessHandler - Adding device samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439 to monitor for launched app: com.medinq.superlines 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,278 [6457169]   INFO - notification.NotificationGroup - Notification group LaunchTaskRunner is already registered 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:48)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:28)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup$Companion.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.kt:93)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup$Companion.toolWindowGroup$default(NotificationGroup.kt:92)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-26 12:54:05,279 [6457170]   INFO - ools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask - Installing application: com.medinq.superlines 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526413ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : installer 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526413ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : Command Dump 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526413ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : get process ids 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526563ms LOG_ERR [23108][23108] : Could not get package user id: run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted
 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526564ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526564ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : CmdCommand::GetApksFromDump 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : processing APK 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:06,969 [6458860]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - Install successfully finished in 1 s 689 ms.. App restart successful without requiring a re-install. 
2021-02-26 12:54:09,280 [6461171]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - startCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:54:49,324 [6501215]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:54:49,324 [6501215]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopAll() 
2021-02-26 12:55:27,086 [6538977]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appBuiltInServerOptions took 15 ms, PropertiesComponent took 16 ms 
2021-02-26 12:55:27,117 [6539008]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=SuperLines, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Ura\AndroidStudioProjects\SuperLines) ProjectView took 16 ms 
2021-02-26 12:55:37,825 [6549716]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2021-02-26 12:55:38,340 [6550231]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appExportableFileTemplateSettings took 16 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum Java heap size is different on each device. You can find out its size by calling [getMemoryClass](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getMemoryClass()). If your app tries to allocate more than this the OutOfMemoryError is thrown regardless of the device's overall RAM situation (even if there is still free RAM). The JVM will call the GC before throwing the exception but if not enough space for the next allocation can be freed (because all of it is used or because it is fragmented / not contiguous) it won't have any alternative but throwing the exception. This heap limit does not apply to the native code which may exceed it depending on how much the OS can spare for your app.

For debugging purposes you may set the [largeHeap](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#largeHeap) attribute in the manifest but that may not solve anything.
You could try to allocate / initialize variables more gradually to in increments or move large data structures to the native side to work around the heap limit. You may also split your app into multiple processes as the heap limit is per process though that's not usually useful in games.
However, on such memory constrained devices (with less 2 GB RAM) there isn't much you can do besides removing features or using lower quality assets. You may want to restrict the devices that can install your game to those with a minimum amount of RAM though I don't think google play has such filters.

Comment: Your advice solved my problem. I set attribute largeHeap = true and the error disappeared

Comment: Glad to hear the exception is no longer thrown. Note however that on some devices the OS might not provide enough extra RAM (or none at all) even with largeHeap=true.

Answer (score 0):

What is the OS version (and Java version) on that phone?  I'll bet it's an earlier release which might have had a bug in it.

Comment: this is samsung-sm_a510f. OS version 7.0.  Program setting: minSdkVersion 19,  targetSdkVersion 30